# Using a DLC purchased by another account

Tags: ps4, psn

I have a disc game on PS4 and I want to buy DLC for it, but my progress is on an account that can't use dollars on its store. If I buy that DLC from another account on the same PS4 can I use it on the account I have my progress in?

Comment: Usually, if the account who purchases the game/dlc has the console set as the main one, every user on that console can download and use its digital contents. But I don't know if this is true also for different region games/dlc

Comment: Thank You pinckerman for replying to my question, from reading Your comment I got the idea that I can just switch accounts since I have the game on a disc, but I want to know if I can share my psplus.

Comment: Yes, you just need that your console is set as the main one by your account with psplus, in  this way every other account should be able to use your psplus games and also play online

Comment: Thank you soo much  your comments helped me thank you again